# Updating Active Directory 'webpage' property

Tags: 2010, my-site, active-directory, user-profile-service

We currently have a SharePoint 2007 environment that has been in use for years now.  When it was set up, it automatically entered information into the Active Directory property 'webpage' for all users that visited it the first time.

We are currently re-creating (not upgrading) our intranet in SharePoint 2010.  I notice that this property isn't updated to the new SharePoint 2010 MySite URL when the user visits the new site collection and their MySite.

How can this property be updated?  Should it have been when users visit their MySite page for the first time?  What is the standard method for updating this value to point to the new SharePoint 2010 MySites?

Does it even need to be updated?  I notice that people that have visited the new 2010 site have a MySite created for them.  When clicking their name when it appears on the site, I am either navigated to the MySite home page, or, if they haven't had their MySite created yet - a standard list item page with their user information.

I would like to update the 'webpage' property in Active Directory regardless, I believe - but I would prefer not to have to run a script for all users in there.  I would prefer SharePoint 2010 perform this operation if that is a valid thing to do.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get prompted you need to "fix" the keys that cause the ActiveX control to load for the PortalConnect12.PersonalSite control. THere are a number of blog posts on this topic, but it appears that they are incorrectly written in SharePoint 2010.

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\PortalConnect12.PersonalSite] 
@="PersonalSite Class"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\PortalConnect12.PersonalSite\CLSID] 
@="{E7339A62-0E31-4A5E-BA3D-F2FEDFBF8BE5}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\PortalConnect12.PersonalSite\CurVer] 
@="PortalConnect12.PersonalSite.1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\PortalConnect12.PersonalSite.1] 
@="PersonalSite Class"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\PortalConnect12.PersonalSite.1\CLSID] 
@="{E7339A62-0E31-4A5E-BA3D-F2FEDFBF8BE5}"

Once done the user will be prompted as you expect in 2007.

Comment: so I added these entries to my local registry, and I received the prompt, but Active Directory still shows my 'webpage' property pointing to the old 2007 site.  Is there a way for SharePoint to update this like it did in 2007 automatically?

Comment: I am not certain, but in 2010 the ability to write back to AD has been added, I am not sure if that replaced the 2007 feature.